# Trying to increase an array size and add a new value

Tags: java, arrays

This is just for a simple java project. Here's the code. Basically all I'm trying to do is increase the size of this array if it is full and then when the user decides to add a value, increase the size and add the value into the array.

```
public void increaseSize(){

    int[] temp = new int[list.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

        temp[i] = list[i];

    }

    list = temp;

}

public void addElement(int newVal){

    if (c == list.length){

        increaseSize();

    }

    list[c] = newVal;
    c++;


}
```

}

import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntegerListTest{

```
static IntegerList list = new IntegerList(10);

//-------------------------------------------------------
// Create a list, then repeatedly print the menu and do what the
// user asks until they quit
//-------------------------------------------------------
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
printMenu();
int choice = input.nextInt();
while (choice != 0)
    {
    dispatch(choice);
    printMenu();
    choice = input.nextInt();
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
// Do what the menu item calls for
//-------------------------------------------------------
public static void dispatch(int choice)
{

Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int loc;
switch(choice)
    {
    case 0: 
    System.out.println("Bye!");
    break;
    case 1:
    System.out.println("How big should the list be?");
    int size = input1.nextInt();
    list = new IntegerList(size);
    list.randomize();
    break;
    case 2:
    list.selectionSort();
    break;
    case 3:
    System.out.print("Enter the value to look for: ");
    loc = list.search(input1.nextInt());
    if (loc != -1)
        System.out.println("Found at location " + loc);
    else
        System.out.println("Not in list");
    break;
    case 4:
    list.print();
    break;
    case 5:
    System.out.print("# to add: ");
    int newnum;
    newnum = input1.nextInt();
    list.addElement(newnum);
    default:
    System.out.println("Sorry, invalid choice");
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
// Print the user's choices
//-------------------------------------------------------
public static void printMenu()
{

System.out.println("\n   Menu   ");
System.out.println("   ====");
System.out.println("0: Quit");
System.out.println("1: Create a new list (** do this first!! **)");
System.out.println("2: Sort the list using selection sort");
System.out.println("3: Find an element in the list using sequential search");
System.out.println("4: Print the list");
System.out.println("5: Add an element to the list.");
System.out.print("\nEnter your choice: ");
}
```

}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerList{

```
private int c;
int[] list; //values in the list

//-------------------------------------------------------
//create a list of the given size
//-------------------------------------------------------
public IntegerList(int size)
{
list = new int[size];
c = 0;
}


//-------------------------------------------------------
//fill array with integers between 1 and 100, inclusive
//-------------------------------------------------------
public void randomize()
{
for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    list[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
//print array elements with indices
//-------------------------------------------------------
public void print()
{
for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    System.out.println(i + ":\t" + list[i]);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
//return the index of the first occurrence of target in the list.
//return -1 if target does not appear in the list
//-------------------------------------------------------
public int search(int target)
{
int location = -1;
for (int i=0; i<list.length && location == -1; i++)
    if (list[i] == target)
    location = i;
return location;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
//sort the list into ascending order using the selection sort algorithm
//-------------------------------------------------------
public void selectionSort()
{
int minIndex;
for (int i=0; i < list.length-1; i++)
    {
    //find smallest element in list starting at location i
    minIndex = i;
    for (int j = i+1; j < list.length; j++)
        if (list[j] < list[minIndex])
            minIndex = j;

    //swap list[i] with smallest element
    int temp = list[i];
    list[i] = list[minIndex];
    list[minIndex] = temp;
    }
}

public void increaseSize(){

    int[] temp = new int[list.length * 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){

        temp[i] = list[i];

    }

    list = temp;

}

public void addElement(int newVal){

    if (c == list.length){

        increaseSize();

    }

    list[c] = newVal;
    c++;


}
```

}

So basically when I use the option to add a value I expect it to be added onto the end.

Ie.  1,3,4 is the original. If I input 6 I want 6 to be at the end of 1,3,4,6. Right now if I enter 6 it becomes 1,3,6

Comment: Well. I print out the array and it has just edited it in to the first index. I want it to be the one that is already in existence, just with this value added on

Comment: what do you mean by edited it into the first index? :)

Comment: The code you have posted looks ok to me. Post the full class and a bit more detail on exactly what you see happen and what you expect to happen.

Comment: yes! sorry I meant to say that

Comment: There's the whole project

Comment: You can't use `list.length` (except in `addElement()` and `increaseSize()` because that is when `c == list.length`). That is your length is in `c`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm confused. What part should be using c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your randomize method doesn't set c - so the pointer is still at the start of the array when you later go to add a new number.

Incidentally you do know that you are essentially recreating `ArrayList` here right? It's fine if you are doing this as a learning exercise but for any proper programming you should be using `ArrayList`.

Comment: Confused. C is given a value elsewhere...what does randomize have to do with it?

Comment: c is 0, c is where new elements are added. Even though you filled the array in randomize you didn't move c on so you are still writing to the start of the list.

Comment: Incidentally you should learn to use a debugger - it will make tracking down this sort of problem much easier. Step through the add method and you can see exactly what is happening.

Comment: So what exact part has to be changed? sorry. quite new to this

Comment: I got it. I changed c to be the size when the list is generated.

Comment: You'd either add `c = list.length;` to the end of your randomize method or use c as the control as in `for(; c < list.length; c++) list[c] = (int)(Math.random() * 100) + 1;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to add an element to array

```
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    a = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1);
    a[a.length - 1] = 4;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: +1 but perhaps you should preface your answer by saying that you *can't* "add an element to an array" - you must create a larger array